# In this beamer, the equation exceed the size of the frame. How do I fix this?

Tags: beamer, equations

In this beamer, the equation exceed the size of the frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}% font de LaTeX
\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usecolortheme{miniframes}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}



\title[Modelamiento de bandas de energia por el metodo de diferencias para las redes             SC,FCC,BCC]{Modelamiento de Bandas de Energia 3D, aproximando la ecuacion de Schrödinger             por el metodo de diferencias finitas, para redes SC,FCC,BCC.\\}
\author[Juan Pablo Muñoz Diaz]{ Director: Elisabeth Restrepo Parra.\\Estudiante: Juan     Pablo Muñoz Diaz\\ \vspace{1cm}Universidad Nacional de Colombia\\ Sede Manizales}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\titlepage
\scriptsize
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Resumen}


\begin{itemize}
\item[a.] Se toma la ecuacion de Shcrodinger Original
\begin{align}
\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\bigg( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2}             {\partial z^2}\bigg)\psi(x,y,z)+V(x,y,z)\psi(x,y,z) =     E\psi(x,y,z)\label{ecu-gen}
\end{align}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: By reformulating your equation or buying a 16:9 projector.

Comment: @percusse: is this question at that kind of primary level?; jejeje

Comment: `\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the option `aspectratio=169` as percusse says in `\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}` to get

[image]

Or use the symbol for Laplacian

```
\begin{align}
\frac{-\hbar²}{2m}∇^{2}ψ(x,y,z)+V(x,y,z)ψ(x,y,z) =     Eψ(x,y,z)\label{ecu-gen}
\end{align}
```

to get

[image]

Or try to split the equation into two lines using amsmath (split/align/multline)

```
\begin{multline}
\frac{-\hbar²}{2m}\bigg( \frac{∂²}{∂ x²}+\frac{∂²}{∂ y²}+\frac{∂²}             {∂ z²}\bigg)ψ(x,y,z)+V(x,y,z)ψ(x,y,z) \\
=     Eψ(x,y,z)\label{ecu-gen}
\end{multline}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another solution with the `aligned` environment and the `\mathllap` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
%\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}% font de LaTeX
\usetheme{Berlin}
%\usecolortheme{miniframes}

%\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nccmath}



\title[Modelamiento de bandas de energia por el metodo de diferencias para las redes SC,FCC,BCC]{Modelamiento de Bandas de Energia 3D, aproximando la ecuacion de Schrödinger por el metodo de diferencias finitas, para redes SC,FCC,BCC.\\}
\author[Juan Pablo Muñoz Diaz]{ Director: Elisabeth Restrepo Parra.\\Estudiante: Juan Pablo Muñoz Diaz\\ \vspace{1cm}Universidad Nacional de Colombia\\ Sede Manizales}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\titlepage
\scriptsize
\end{center}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Resumen}


\begin{itemize}
\item[a.] Se toma la ecuacion de Shrodinger Original
\begin{equation}
\label{ecu-gen}
\begin{aligned}
\mathllap{\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}}\bigg( \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}+\mfrac{\partial^2} {\partial z^2}\bigg)\psi(x,y,z) & + V(x,y,z)\psi(x,y,z)\\
    & = E\psi(x,y,z)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]